# Launch a docker-compose service several times with different variables

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose with a service I'd love to launch several times with various env variables. The idea is to launch the service several times, notably on a series of ports.

My current strategy is to copy and paste the service name N times, N being the number of time I need to launch the service, but that seems very unefficient.

Reproducible example:

> `app/app.js`

```
var http = require('http');

var name = process.env.NAME || "Jack"
var port = process.env.PORT || 1234

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(`Hi ${name}!`);
});
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on port ${port}`));
```

> `app/Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

> `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
    node:
        build: app
        environment:
            - NAME=${NAME}
            - PORT=${PORT}
        command: node app.js
        expose:
            - "${PORT}"
        ports:
            - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
```

What I want to do is to be able to do :

- `NAME=joe PORT=1234 docker-compose up -d node`
- `NAME=jack PORT=1235 docker-compose up -d node`

And I now have two services, one on each port. localhost:1234 show "hello joe", localhost:1235 "Hello jack". Right now if I do that the same service is relaunched.

Things I have tried so far:

- The `--scale` options, unfortunately I couldn't find how to control the env var settings
- Using the `container_name` entry in the service definition. Unfortunately it seems that it's still the same service launched and renamed

Comment: Have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203272/docker-compose-scaling-with-unique-environment-variable). Write a script that updates the .env on each lunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can launch all of the containers in the same `docker-compose.yml` file then you can trim down a couple of options to make the amount of syntax more palatable.

There's no specific requirement that the process inside a container listen on the same port that's being published on the host, and in modern Docker `expose:` means almost nothing.  That means you don't specifically need to configure a `PORT` environment variable; you can always start the container process on its default port 1234 and just remap that per-container.  You also don't need to repeat the default `CMD` from the Dockerfile.

So an all-in-one Docker Compose setup for what you show could look like

```yaml
version: '3' # 2 vs. 3 doesn't really matter here
services:
  joe:
    build: app
    environment:
      - NAME=joe
    ports: '1234:1234'
  jack:
    build: app
    environment:
      - NAME=jack
    ports: '1235:1234'
```

---

If you want to use a series of `docker-compose` invocations as you've shown, Compose has an internal notion of a "project", and it keeps track of the state of the containers in a project.  By default the current directory's local name is used as the project name.  In your `docker-compose up` command, Compose sees that you've changed the port mapping and environment settings for the `node` container in the same single project, so it replaces the existing container.

To tell Compose that there are different projects, you need the [`docker-compose -p`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) option

```sh
NAME=joe PORT=1234 docker-compose -p joe up -d node
NAME=jack PORT=1235 docker-compose -p jack up -d node
```

Note that you will need to repeat this option on *every* `docker-compose` command invocation.  If you use non-Compose commands like `docker ps` you will be able to see the project name included as part of the container name (`joe_node_1`, `jack_node_1`).

Comment: As a one-liner
`NAME=joe PORT=1234 bash -c 'docker-compose -p \$NAME up -d node'`

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

As you can see the mentioned link you need to create you need to have a .env file at the same level as your compose file .

Now to run your same compose file multiple time without changing the parameters manually create a sample file say sample_file with your env variable as key value like "Key1=value_1" "key2=value_2" Now use sed to replace value_1 and value_2 and create a new file with .env and pipe the command with docker compose up -d

*"sed -i -e 's/value_1/1234/g' -e 's/value_2/Joe/g' sample_file>sample_file.env|docker-compose up -d node"*

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this relaunches the same service several times, not various services :/